# How would peer review happen for meta spoiler answers?

Tags: discussion

For some questions asking what kind of TV series/movies satisfy certain conditions, there may be answers where saying the name of the TV series/movie is a spoiler. Eg I just asked [Besides iCarly, has there ever been an (official) adult sequel to a kids' series?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/117455/besides-icarly-has-there-ever-been-an-official-adult-sequel-to-a-kids-series/) and then I just gave [this answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/117455/besides-icarly-has-there-ever-been-an-official-adult-sequel-to-a-kids-series/117547#117547) but I had to block it in spoiler because the name of the series as an answer is a spoiler of the series. At the very least I gave a little hint that the series is from Nickelodeon.

How would peer review happen if people don't really want to spoil themselves?

Comment: Why is your answer a spoiler?  Perhaps the reason *why* it may be an adult series is a spoiler but the name of the show is surely not?

Comment: Also ... peer review cannot happen if people are avoiding all spoilers.

Comment: @iandotkelly Saying the name of the show gives a hint to people watching it. But I guess I'll split up the 2 spoilers. Thanks. Post as answer: split up the name and the reason ?

Comment: Gives a hint about what exactly?  That it contains adult themes?  Seriously - it doesn't need spoiler markup.

Comment: @iandotkelly edited comment.

Comment: I...don't quite get what this question is actually about. Are you generally asking how people could read questions/answers when they don't want to unhide spoilers? In that case, no, they can't. But then someone else has to review the posts. That's also why the essence of the post should be understandable without the spoiler blocks or otherwise they need to be avoided (as in, no spoiler block used, not as in removing the information altogether). But like ian I really don't get why your answer is a spoiler block at all, let alone what it actually is you mean with "peer review".

Comment: @NapoleonWilson You got it right and that's exactly why I did what I did (split up the answer into name spoiler and reason spoiler) based on iandotkelly's comment

Comment: But @BCLC .... you didn't really understand what I was saying.  You're overthinking this and the entire answer doesn't need spoiler markup.  You cannot worry too much about people being spoiled in the review queue.

Comment: That a "show contains LBGTQ characters" is not the same level of spoiler as "the main character is actually already dead" for example.

Comment: @iandotkelly I agree it's not the whole. That's why after Napoleon Wilson's comment I split it up and identified what was being spoiled. The name and then the reason.

Answer (score 6):

### You are considerably overblowing the importance of spoilers

The fact that a show contains LGBTQ characters is considerably less of a spoiler than you think.  Its not like

> the main protagonist of the show was dead throughout movie

or

> a major character dies

or

> The protagonist and his best friend are the same person

It's literally impossible to avoid spoilers on this site if you consider *any* aspect of the plot or characterization to be a spoiler, no matter how trivially unimportant.

Moderators and high-rep users here regularly edit spoilers out of question titles so that people do not get inadvertently spoiled on the home page.

Comment: If a question is about S02E04 then S01E01 - S02E03 need not be spoiler marked right?