# Why was my flag to suggest a revision declined but then later the revision was done?

Tags: support

See [(Avengers spoilers) here](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/4822/2) re my meta question [How would peer review happen for meta spoiler answers?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4821/how-would-peer-review-happen-for-meta-spoiler-answers/4822#4822):

iandotkelly spoils an Avengers movie when trying to give an answer with examples of generic spoilers but then gives an actual spoiler without saying beforehand that it was a spoiler for a specific movie.

This was my flag whose contents are just a copy of the comment I typed on the answer:

> This is kind of disgusting. Why would you spoil [redacted by BCLC]? I think you should've put prior like [avengers spoiler] or something – BCLC 10 hours ago   declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

iandotkelly's response to me was something like

> 'I don't know if you're serious or not.'

I recall my reply was something like

> 'It seemed like you were giving generic spoiler examples, but then you used a real example without specifying what you are spoiling.' I then linked to a similar discussion I had in [anime stackexchange](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4511/should-we-say-the-episode-chapter-season-in-the-question-to-help-avoid-spoilers) (and [here](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2654/should-this-question-have-avoided-spoilers-in-the-title-or-not)).

Appendix:

I must say I am very disappointed with the way stackexchange handles spoilers, as if we were in youtube comments or something. In other sites like, say, reddit, spoilers are taken very seriously. For example, [r/anime even has kind of spoiler tag called 'meta-spoiler'](https://www.reddit.com/r/anime/wiki/rules#wiki_do_not_post_untagged_spoilers) where you use it when the title of the show spoils something.

P.S. iandotkelly Why did you delete the comments and remove your avengers spoiler if I am 'considerably overblowing the importance of spoilers' ? Why don't you include a confession that you spoiled avengers for me in your answer and see if you still get upvotes?

Comment: I removed the spoiler because it was clearly bothering you and in the spirit of making a concession towards your strong feelings in the matter.  I trust this is not a problem?  I didn't delete comments or deal with your flag - I considered it a conflict of interest since you had taken offense to my slightly tongue in cheek example of a spoiler on a 3 year old movie.

Comment: Re: your "appendix" ... this is a collaboratively edited and managed site.  Changes in policy are discussed through this meta site.  You could raise substantive, practical policy changes here, and discuss in a positive manner.

Answer (score 9):

First of all, iandotkelly neither handled that flag nor deleted any of those comments.

But let's start at the beginning, he included a spoiler in his meta answer about spoilers. Maybe that was a bit careless or maybe he didn't think anyone would take it serious. But obviously it bothered you and after the corresponding comment discussion, he changed his answer according to your critique and turned it into a generic spoiler text, the one we all see now. And everything was fine.

I arrived after the fact and saw the flag as well as the comment discussion about a version of the answer that wasn't really relevant anymore. I have to say, I wasn't a fan of the wording in your flag anyway (I'd say I found it somewhat...disgusting, but well...), nor is it really something worth flagging, as it can (and actually *was*) solved by editing the post.

I don't know if your flag came before or after ian's edit, but really it doesn't quite matter. I saw that it wasn't relevant anymore and declined it for that and the other reasons above. Then I also removed the now obsolete comment discussion about a version of the answer noone really cared about anymore.

I really don't know what the point is of making a stink about this after the fact now. Fine, ian put a problematic spoiler into his answer, you told him so and he changed it, end of story. No bad spoilers in the answer anymore and everyone is happy. There's really no need to hold a grudge on him for that or hang onto flags that lost their relevance long before they were handled. (And his comment as to "considerably overblowing the importance of spoilers' was *not* about the spoiler in his answer, rather than about the matter of your meta question.)

---

Your appendix isn't really something we can help you with, though. We're discussing the content of movies and TV-shows here and a lot of that is prone to spoil that content. We try to keep question titles resonably spoiler free. But if the fact that a kids' show deals with homosexuality is a spoiler for you, you're kind of out of luck on this site with the level of what you regard a spoiler and wish to be protected from in the posts you read and write yourself.